# Converting project to react native init

Tags: react-native, create-react-app, expo

Firstly I created my project with create-react-native-app and I'm developing my app with npm start and I have expo installed on my emulator. How can I convert these project into react native init, I don't want to use expo anymore...I don't neeed any api-es from them...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best resource for this is in the create-react-native-app repository. Try having a look [here](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) to get started.

The short answer is to use `npm run eject`

If you have experience generating signed APKs for Android and code signing with iOS then you shouldn't run into too much trouble.

If you don't, then take the time to go through the [Android docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) and also [this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device) should help you get up on running on iOS as well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your project using the command create-react-native-app, you may create a react native project by following "Building Projects with Native Code" of the getting start guide: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html.
Here you will find out how to:
1. Set up the environment.
2. Installation of phone emulator.
3. Connection of your phone via USB for testing.
4. Create a project using the react-native init command.

Comment: I have almost finished app with create-react-native-app and I want to move to "react-native init" ...